# Inter die vs Intra die process variation

Tags: semiconductors, vlsi, fabrication

Due to fabrication process, there will be variations, among wafers as well as among dies across a wafer.
My question is that what variations are significant between dies? And what variations are significant between wafers?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Way too many to just list. You need to do your own research and ask about exactly what confuses you.

Comment: My [survey paper on process variation](https://www.academia.edu/19490711/A_Survey_Of_Architectural_Techniques_for_Managing_Process_Variation) may be of help. (The question is not very clear to me.)

Answer (score 1):

The variations between dies are somewhat dependent on the distance between the dies, and also generally on the position of the die on the wafer -- often you find patterns of variation in a ring around the edge of the wafer, or a crescent shape around the edge.

What is significant is a qualitative term, but in certain cases, those variations can cause some die to have parameters that are out of spec.